# Error on Starting computer after upgrade

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, release-upgrade

The Ubuntu upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 get problem, While the time was remaining about 4 mins the current interrupts so the computer get started and it says small file expected than header....

and the computer gets hangs upon.

What may be the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning,

If you can get to the terminal or from <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` . If that doesn't work try this option `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing` . If you can't get into your standard build try using this in recovery mode.

Thanks.